# How to mange Incoming call from client on one TWILIO number (number used by multiple users)

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I want to integrate Twilio into my app(JAVA SPRING), now I come up with the fact that if I bought only one Twilio number then I can call multiple clients at the same time from different users.
But what if Multiple clients calling the same number if eg. I am having 5 users having same Twilio number.

What will happen in that case? 
**We need to buy a separate number for each user OR we can manage with the same number.**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This all depends on how you want your number to handle incoming calls. For example, you can set up a number to forward all incoming calls onto one user's number with the following [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml):

```
<Response>
  <Dial><Number>+XXXXXXXXXX</Number></Dial>
</Response>
```

However, if you don't want all calls going to that person only you could forward them to all your users at the same time. Then when one answers the other calls will drop. You can do this with multiple [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) elements:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+XXXXXXXXXX</Number>
    <Number>+YYYYYYYYYY</Number>
    <Number>+ZZZZZZZZZZ</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

You could also do some more dynamic operations. For example, you could look up the number that is dialling in and match it against your customer database and then connect it to a particular user on your side. Or you could forward calls to different numbers based on the time of day if your users work different shifts.

To get even more complicated, but gain more control, you could investigate [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter) which lets you set up different workflows and queues.

If you want to provide each of your users a direct number that they can be contacted on, then you may want to purchase one number for each of them.

There is plenty of choice and opportunity with Twilio to build the solution that you want. I recommend taking a look around the [voice documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/) to see the various tools you can build with.

Comment: Great to hear that! If it did help, could you mark my answer as correct so that others can see it worked too? Thanks!

Comment: I will work on this after some days, right now I got some other stuff, sure I will mark it. Thanks.